# Getting request data synchronously in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, request, synchronous

So I have an interesting issue. 
Here is how it can be summed up quickly and in a generic manner:
(1) Get a property value or list from the DB through a python based API endpoint - property 
(2) Use the request result to set for an object - customObject["customProperty"].

Between 1 and 2 I need to wait for the request to return the value.
How can I achieve this?

```
function mainWrapperFunction() {
    var property = apiRequestFunction();
    // I need to wait for the result to return from the API request before going on
    customObject["customProperty"] = property;
}
```

Comment: You should look into `Promises`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

```
async function mainWrapperFunction() {
    var property = await apiRequestFunction();
    // I need to wait for the result to return from the API request before going on
    customObject["customProperty'] = property;
}
```

Need to return a Promise from `apiRequestFunction();` function like below -

```
function apiRequestFunction() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      resolve('Your value here');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
async function mainWrapperFunction() {
    var property = await apiRequestFunction();
    // I need to wait for the result to return from the API request before going on
    customObject['customProperty'] = property;
}
```

for more details about asyc functions https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/async_function

Comment: How do you know that `apiRequestFunction();` return a promise?

Comment: He write that the function is an API request